# When lazy loading directive, it's never run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to lazy load a directive. It is loaded and defined, but then it's never run on the html. How do i get angular to run the directive after it's lazy loaded?

```
.config(function ($compileProvider, routes, $provide) {

    //Lazy define
    $compileProvider.directive('myDirective', function ($rootScope, $location, $filter) {

        console.log( "This IS called" );

        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log( "This is NEVER called");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

If I don't lazy load it, it is called.

**EDIT: This also does not work:**

```
.config(function ($compileProvider, routes, $provide) {

    //Lazy define
    $compileProvider.directive('myDirective', function ($rootScope, $location, $filter) {

        console.log( "This IS called" );

        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              console.log( "This is NEVER called");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the way you're defining your directive is valid. This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538665/how-can-directives-be-lazy-loaded-in-angularjs

Comment: @EricWei Changing it to match what some of the answers suggest still doesn't work. Check my update.

Comment: I have it working for me in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qhrgWGiafJYOqnfxBKG9?p=preview

Comment: @EricWei You're not lazy loading it. Try defining it on a button click (save the `$compileProvider.directive` and it won't work. It's because your definition happens before angular finishes all its bootstrapping.

Comment: @EricWei Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Co762oSuw0rbHHbSvfBl?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i get angular to run the directive after it's lazy loaded?

Use an `ng-if` directive in the HTML.

```
  <body ng-app='test'>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div my-directive ng-if="defined"></div>
    <button ng-click="defineIt()">Define it</button><br>
  </body>
```

By setting the `defined` variable to `true` **after** the directive is lazy loaded, the `ng-if` directive will use the `$compile` service to compile the lazy loaded directive.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/vpWxsS6eRJK4cBGRJBMr?p=preview).

Comment: bruh ur teh smartz